# Let $V$ be a linear space and $S,T : V \to V$ linear transformations then if $ImST = \{0\}$ then $ImT \subseteq KerS$ or $KerS =V$ or $KerT =V$ or....

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a linear space and $S,T : V \to V$ linear transformations then ,
>
> 1. if $ImST = \{0\}$ then $KerS =V$ or $KerT =V$
> 2. if $ImST = \{0\}$ then $ImS \subseteq KerT$
> 3. if $ImST = \{0\}$ then $ImT \subseteq KerS$

The correct answer is the third option and I am trying to understand why
I tried looking at rules and such that might be related to the question such as

$ImST \subseteq ImS$ , $KerT \subseteq KerST$ , $ImST =S(ImT)$ and $dimKerT+dimImT = dimV$

for the first one I tried $dimKerT+dimImT = dimV$ , $dimKerST+dimImST = dimV$ and $dimKerST+0 = dimV$ so $dimkerST=dimV \rightarrow kerST=V $ but $KerT \subseteq KerST$ and this confuses me that then $KerT \subseteq V$? so the first is not right?

the second and third I did not know how to prove or begin with

Appreciate any tips and help.. the final answer is not important I am trying to understand this because I feel lost thank you!

Comment: as a tip: if you feel lost on problems like this try playing around with $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$ diagonal matrices for $S$ and $T$'

Comment: @user8675309 sounds really interesting , can you please give a bit more detail? I don't see how i can relate a matrix to this

Comment: there's not much to it other than playing around with extremely simple examples like $\Big\{\mathbf 0, I_2, \begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\  0 &0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0& 0\\  0 &1\end{bmatrix}\Big\}$ then recognize that they all commute so when choosing S and T from this set $ST=TS$ and (e.g. in context of 2) of course im $S$ is killed by $\ker T$ when TS = 0.  So augment the set with a single simple non-commuting matrix.  I prefer an upper triangular matrix like  $\begin{bmatrix}0& 1\\  0 &0\end{bmatrix}$ then check again.  So really it's a set of diagonal matrices plus one non-diagonal.

Comment: If I can can add a suggestion, maybe the most interesting part of the question is showing why 1 and 2 are false. Try to show it !

Comment: @InfiniteLooper Thank you , I failed to prove the 2nd option , but I tried the first one as I showed I am not sure if it is right

Comment: it's really basic, and does not really relates on the notion of dimension (it stays valid in infinite dimension)

Comment: maybe open a new question with what you tried and so on. Try first to understand what it means for $S$ to be such that $ker(S) = V$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any $A : V \to V$ we have $Im(A) = 0 $ if and only if $A=0$.

$Im(ST) = 0$ is equivalent to $ST= 0$;

ie $ \forall x \in V, S(T(x)) = 0$

ie $\forall y \in Im(T), S(y)=0$

ie $\forall y \in Im(T), y \in Ker(S)$

ie $Im(T) \subset Ker(S)$